# Prove that if $ \ P(A|B) > P(A) > 0$ then $ \ P(A^{c} |B) < P(A^{c})$

Tags: probability, proof-verification

Question:

Prove that if $ \ P(A|B) > P(A) > 0$ then $ \ P(A^{c} |B) < P(A^{c})$

My attempt:

Assume$ \ P(A|B) > P(A) > 0$

WTS $ \ P(A^{c} |B) < P(A^{c})$

$ \ P(A|B) > P(A) > 0 \implies -P(A|B) < -P(A) < 0 \implies 1 - P(A|B) < 1 - P(A) \implies P(A^{c}|B) < P(A^{c})$

Is this the correct approach to prove this statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This is a correct approach, although if someone doesn't understand, you may want to flesh out why
$$1-P(A|B) = P(A^c|B)$$
We can prove this purely algebraically using the definition $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$.

Using this we have
$$1-P(A|B)=1-\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(B)-P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$
We can now expand $P(B)$ as
$$P(B)=P(A^c \cap B) + P(A \cap B)$$
And then our expression reduces to
$$\frac{P(A^c \cap B)}{P(B)} =P(A^c|B)$$

Comment: Could you show me how to prove the statement you mentioned?

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel Yes, I will add it below!

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel, $$1-P(A|B)=\frac{P(B)-P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(B\setminus A)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(B\cap A^c)}{P(B)}=P(A^c|B)$$

Comment: There's a more visual way to prove it though I wonder if it would be considered rigorous. $P(A|B)$ denotes the probability of $A$ happening given that $B$ has already happened, so $1-P(A|B)$ gives the complement of this event, which is the probability of $A$ **not happening** given that $B$ has already happened, which is $P(A^c|B)$.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas I think it is perfectly rigorous, as the idea directly translates into the algebra.